# Spring MVC @MatrixVariable form data binding

Tags: spring-mvc

I have controller method for form submission. This method accepts one @RequestParam and one @MatrixVariable. I have to use this method for processing some item with dynamic properties. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/item/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addItem(@RequestParam("itemName") String itemName, @MatrixVariable MultiValueMap<String, String>
                properties) {
    // do some stuff...
    return "redirect:/items";
}
```

Everything works fine with direct URL but how have the form looks, its action and its inputs to satisfy provided controller method. I use thymeleaf as template engine.
Thanks is advance!

Comment: You can use hidden fields and text fields with same name to form an array. But for matrix variable which is widely used in JAX-RS as a url fetch, these can not be used with jsp mechanism unless we have accurate matching strings for matrixvariable.

Comment: Thanks! I actually need some solution to handle dynamic properties on the form. Currently I use `@RequestParam Map<String, String>` as temporal solution, but I don't like it, its requires a lot of custom code.

Comment: _"Currently I use @RequestParam Map<String, String> as temporal solution, but I don't like it"_ And how would `MultiValueMap<String, String>` differ from your current solution? As a side note: How could `"/item/add"` possibly be a `GET` request? You send something to the server.

Comment: 1. Map<String, String> contains all fields from the submitted form, MultiValueMap<String, String> has to contain only MatrixVariable.

Comment: 2. Yes, I need to have form submit with method get